# Failed to parse time string when trying to convert MysQl Timestamp to Time Ago

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to convert MysQl timestamp to display `time ago` but I get this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (1493324845)

**script**

```
<?php 
//convert timestamp to time ago
$start_date = new DateTime();
$time = strtotime($streamuser['Datetime']);
$dbDate = new DateTime($time);
$currDate = new DateTime();
$interval = $currDate->diff($dbDate);
?>
<span><?php  echo $interval->d." days ".$interval->h." hours";?></span>
```

MysQl Timestamp format is `2017-04-27 22:27:25`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting the error because I was trying to parse string where date_diff() expects datetime object. This works for me:

```
   <?php 
    //convert timestamp to time ago
    $dbDate =$streamuser['Datetime'];
    $date = new DateTime($dbDate);
    $now = new DateTime();
   ?>
   <span style="font-size:smaller;">
   <?php  echo $date->diff($now)->format("%d days, %h hours and %i minutes");?> ago</span>
```